# How to draw object in PictureBox c#?

Tags: c#, winforms, picturebox

I trying draw a rectangles in PictureBox by mouse click:

```
    private void MyPictureBoxMouseClick(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        using (Graphics g = MyPictureBox.CreateGraphics())
        {
            var pen = new Pen(Color.Black, 2);
            g.DrawRectangle(pen, e.X, e.Y, 50, 50);

            pen.Dispose();
        }
    }
```

And rectangles are drawning. But when i move mouse beyond the PictureBox all rectangles are disappear. How to avoid it?

**UPDATE**
I added a Paint event:

```
  private List<Rectangle> Rectangles { set; get; }
        private void MyPictureBoxPaint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
    {
        using (Graphics g = MyPictureBox.CreateGraphics())
        {
            var pen = new Pen(Color.Black, 2);
            foreach (var rect in Rectangles)
            {
                g.DrawRectangle(pen, rect); 
            }

             pen.Dispose();
        }
    }

    private void MyPictureBoxMouseClick(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        Rectangles.Add(new Rectangle(e.X, e.Y, 50, 50));
        MyPictureBox.Refresh();
    }
```

But now rectangles not drawning.

**Update**

Oh it was my mistake.

```
g.DrawRectangle(pen, rect);  -> e.Graphics.DrawRectangle(pen, rect);
```

Comment: Could you be more specific about the disappearing rectangles?

Comment: You need to store your primitives in a list and then draw from the list to the picture box. Currently, they are lost at the next redraw of the picturebox.

Comment: Did you try hooking into the `Draw` event? I think you need to be there to do this ;)

Comment: When you edited your question care to notify the answerers via comment, otherwise they wont see your question is updated.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, you're drawing over the picture box. When the next paint messgae arrives, picturebox re-paints itself again at that time it'll overwrite your rectangles.

You either need to draw it in `Paint` event in order to make your rectangles survive or you can Draw over the `PictureBox.Image` so it will stay there.

For your edit: You need to use `e.Graphics` property. For instance following code works for me.

```
private void MyPictureBoxPaint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
{
    Graphics g = e.Graphics;
    using (var pen = new Pen(Color.Black, 2))
    {
        foreach (var rect in Rectangles)
        {
            g.DrawRectangle(pen, rect);
        }
    }
}
```